# How do I subclass a variable with an IBOutlet?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, ios8

All descendants of my specific class are to have a `UILabel` instance variable. So in my parent class I have `var label: UILabel`. I want to have it in the sublclass as well, but as an `IBOutlet`. How do I do this?

I added the `IBOutlet` of the same name, and added weak to both variable declarations. But I get an error about "Cannot override with a stored property".

How should I be doing this? And is it possible to not have to instantiate the superclass' version as I just want it for subclassing?

Comment: It isn't clear why you'd even want to do this. Why not just have a different instance variable in the subclass? What's the problem you are _really_ trying to solve?

Comment: @matt I have a view controller I'm dequeueing that can be one of two different kinds of similar view controllers. I want to use polymorphism to use their superclass to do the operations. Is there a better way to be doing that?

Comment: @DougSmith edited answer have a look

Comment: @DougSmith you can override `getter and setter` and can connect the outlet to subclass

Comment: I still do not see, from your "explanation", why these need to be the _same_ instance variable. All you need is a pointer, common to the superclass, which then points to one variable in class A and to another variable in class B.

Comment: @matt If I understand your suggestion that's what I'm trying to do: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089654/how-would-i-use-polymorphism-to-allow-a-method-to-accept-multiple-classes-but-w/25090031#25090031) for a more broad overview, but I think we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: Maybe, but that question, the way you pose it, is full of false assumptions and misconceptions. For example: "However, if I want the nameLabel to be an outlet, it doesn't seem settable as I couldn't have the variable in every subclass to wire the view up to in IB." Of course you could. Nib-loading works by class and the name of the outlet. How do you think every UIViewController's main `view` outlet gets hooked up? It isn't magic, or mysterious. If a nib has an outlet, it will find that property in its owner when it loads (indeed, if the property is _not_ there, you crash).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add the `IBOutlet` modifier in the superclass.

Comment: How do I then link up the views to the IBOutlet variables?

Comment: The same way as you would without subclassing it. Just set your ViewController to use your subclass and Control+drag the components.

Comment: If I include it in the subclass so I can Control+drag the components I get the same error.

Comment: This only works if you have access to the superclass…

Answer (score 20):

By doing so you are `re-declaring` the `label` property in a subclass. `IBOutlet` is just a compiler notion for working with the Interface Builder.

In Swift *stored properties* can not be overridden or redeclared in a subclass. They can only be inherited.

However you can override the `getter` and `setter` of a `properties` in subclasses to provide extra validations or functionalities. Refer to the Swift guide: [override `getter setter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-XID_296)

**You need to declare your property in superClass with `IBOutlet`**.

Or you can make a different property in your subclass. As also there is no meaning if you are connecting your property in one of subclasses(super class may have other) and you are not providing this implementation to other subclasses of your superclass.

**EDIT**: You can also set `label` outlet to two different `viewControllers`of your `SuperClass` from story board if you give `Subclasses` names in storyboard to different view Controllers.

Just define

```
 class SuperClass{
     @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! = nil

 }
```

`SubClass1` repersent  `view controller1` in storyboard derived from `SuperClass`
`SubClass2` repersent another `view controller2` in storyboard derived  from `SuperClass`

Than Go to `Assistant Editor` and open `SuperClass` one side and other side `view controller1` and connect outlet from `SuperClass` to `label` in storyBoard in `view controller1`.Drag from `SuperClass` `label` to storyBoard  in `view controller1`

[image]

Now again  open `SuperClass` one side and other side `view controller2` and connect outlet from `SuperClass` to `label` in storyBoard in `view controller2`.Drag from `SuperClass` `label` to storyBoard  in `view controller2`

If you click on `SuperClass` outlet than you will see two labels conneted to different viewControllers

Comment: Interesting. Investigating.

Comment: I simply dont understand the english... Can someone that understands what's going on here please revise this answer. Thanks

Comment: Seems like this solution does not work if the parent class is generic. Can you confirm, please?

Answer (score 5):

Agreed that the short answer is simply:

> "Just add the `@IBOutlet` modifier in the superclass."

One note though:  if you will be exposing the ViewController in which the `@IBOutlet` is defined via a framework (with Carthage), you will need to add the `public` attribute to the variable definition. **EDIT:  instead, use `open` access keyword`.**

Let's say you have a view controller **CustomViewController** subclassing **UITableViewController**, which you will build in the Carthage-delivered framework.  Everything which should be accessible to the consumer application should be tagged `public`:

```
public class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

@IBOutlet public var myBackgroundView: UIView!
@IBOutlet public weak var myLabel: UILabel!
```

The nice thing about this approach (and I'm *totally* on-board with this use case) is that you can do the IBOutlet mapping in Interface Builder on the superclass, then switch the class of the Scene to the subclass, while retaining all of the mappings.

E.g.: **SubclassedCustomViewController**

```
import UIKit
import mymodule

class SubclassedCustomViewController: CustomViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        myLabel.text = "My special subclass text"
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this question was posted a while ago, but since I just struggled with the same issue and finally came up with a solution, I figured I would still post my findings...

I understand the problem to be as follows (at least that's the one I solved):

*How to have class A inherit from class B, with each class having its own XIB file with the some common IBOutlet properties?* The goal being to be able to have the super class handle the actions related to the IBOutlets that are common to its subclass(es), while still being able to use Interface Builder to design the interface for the subclass(es).*

In order to do so:

- Make the IBOutlet connections in the superclass from the
  superclass' XIB files
- Make the IBOutlet connections in the subclass from the subclass' XIB
  files, with the same IBOutlet property names as in the superclass for the ones you need to inherit.
- Delete the declaration of the IBOutlet variables in the subclass

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76393268/2704776)

But essentially hook your sub classes up to IBoutlets in the sub class just like you normally would, then create the super class, inherit from the subs and then paste the iboutlets into the super class.  Your connections are still looking at the sub class, but that class is looking at the super class.