# How would I use polymorphism to allow a method to accept multiple classes, but with IBOutlets?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, iboutlet

I have a specific method that accepts a `UIView` object, and I want to pass objects to it that can be of one of two classes. So say it accepts a `UIView` that represents an animal, I want to be able to pass a `DogView` and a `CatView` or other animal-type classes potentially.

Within that method I want to set the `nameLabel` view, which all animals have. How do I set it up so I'd be able to do this?

My first reaction was to have a super class (such as `AnimalView`) that has the `nameLabel` variable on it, and then subclass it for each new animal. However, if I want the `nameLabel` to be an outlet, it doesn't seem settable as I couldn't have the variable in every subclass to wire the view up to in IB.

I then tried a `Protocol`, but that's not polymorphic and I wouldn't be able to access the nameLabel property through a generic superclass, could I? Unlike Objective-C I couldn't ask for a `UIView <ProtocolName>` and it would then allow me to ask for it.

How should I be doing this? I just want to be able to pass different kind of objects and have it be compatible with Interface Builder. Should I be approaching it completely differently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I subclass a variable with an IBOutlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088668/how-do-i-subclass-a-variable-with-an-iboutlet)

Comment: @Aaron I feel they're different questions and the other is outlining one specific, particular solution.

Comment: Just declare it in a superclass. In Interface Builder if you go to the connections inspector, it will be there to hook up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can connect outlet of `label` to different `viewControllers` with your `SuperClass` from story board** if your different `viewControlelrs` in storyboard reperset by `Subclasses`(derived from SuperClass) names in storyboard.

1)Just define

```
 class SuperClass{
     @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! = nil

 }
```

`SubClass1` repersent  `view controller1` in storyboard derived from `SuperClass`
`SubClass2` repersent another `view controller2` in storyboard derived  from `SuperClass`

2)Than Go to `Assistant Editor` and open `SuperClass` one side and other side `view controller1` and connect outlet from `SuperClass` to `label` in storyBoard in `view controller1`.Drag from `SuperClass` `label` to storyBoard  in `view controller1`
[image]

3)Now again  open `SuperClass` one side and other side `view controller2` and connect outlet from `SuperClass` to `label` in storyBoard in `view controller2`.Drag from `SuperClass` `label` to storyBoard  in `view controller2`

If you click on `SuperClass` outlet than you will see two labels conneted to different viewControllers

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `IBOutlet` in a `superclass`, `AnimalView`. Then in Interface Builder, once you have set the custom `UIView's` class in the Identity inspector to be `DogView`, go to the Connections Inspector and your `nameLabel` will be there.

```
@interface Parent : UIView

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;

@end

@interface Child : Parent

@end
```

[image]