# How do I hook up a view in Interface Builder to an IBOutlet defined in a superclass from another framework in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, iboutlet

Prior to Xcode 11 I could easily attach a view (label, switch, e.t.c) to an IBOutlet defined on a superclass, if I had the inspector window open and command clicked to my view (In this case a subclass of a `UITableViewCell` subclass it would open the superclass in the inspector window and I could attach to the `IBOutlet`. In Xcode 11 however it seems that when command clicking through to the "definition" this opens in the LHS panel, which replaces my storyboard or xib file with the views superclass.

Is there any way to open the superclass alongside the xib/storyboard any more in Xcode 11? My framework is a pre-compiled framework so I can't access the source files to open them in a new panel in Xcode.

Thought it might be wise to include a class hierarchy

`LargeHeaderTableViewCell -> TableViewCell -> UITableViewCell`

`TableViewCell` is within a pre-compiled framework (Installed using Carthage)

Edit:

To frustrate matters further... I can get the class definition of `TableViewCell` open next to my `xib` file (In a panel), however it seems you can only attach to IBOutlets in the `assistant` editor, not in a standard Xcode panel/tab/whatever you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer (eventually) in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088668/how-do-i-subclass-a-variable-with-an-iboutlet)

> I realize that this question was posted a while ago, but since I just
>   struggled with the same issue and finally came up with a solution, I
>   figured I would still post my findings...
>
> I understand the problem to be as follows (at least that's the one I
>   solved):
>
> How to have class A inherit from class B, with each class having its
>   own XIB file with the some common IBOutlet properties? The goal being
>   to be able to have the super class handle the actions related to the
>   IBOutlets that are common to its subclass(es), while still being able
>   to use Interface Builder to design the interface for the
>   subclass(es).*
>
> In order to do so:
>
> Make the IBOutlet connections in the superclass from the superclass'
>   XIB files Make the IBOutlet connections in the subclass from the
>   subclass' XIB files, with the same IBOutlet property names as in the
>   superclass for the ones you need to inherit. Delete the declaration of
>   the IBOutlet variables in the subclass